# Trouble in prisma Schema

Tags: node.js, prisma

This is my Schema in prisma:

```
model users {
  id            Int       @id @default(12)
  email         String    @unique
  firstName     String?
  lastName      String?
  password      String?
}
```

This is the error when I run npx prisma studio

PrismaClientUnknownRequestError3 [PrismaClientUnknownRequestError]:
[2022-06-15T08:29:10.827Z] Invalid `prisma.users.findMany()` invocation:
[2022-06-15T08:29:10.833Z]   PANIC in libs\prisma-models\src\record.rs:161:30
[2022-06-15T08:29:10.845Z] Invalid coercion encountered: ConversionFailure("Uuid(40ca7fbd-7a7e-4e34-9aa8-89a7f6048a6b)", "Int")
[2022-06-15T08:29:10.857Z] This is a non-recoverable error which probably happens when the Prisma Query Engine has a panic.
[2022-06-15T08:29:10.859Z] https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/new?body=Hi+Prisma+Team%21+My+Prisma+Client+just+crashed.+This+is+the+report%3A%0A%23%23+Versions%0A%0A%7C+Name++++++++++++%7C+Version++++++++++++%7C%0A%7C-----------------%7C--------------------%7C%0A%7C+Node++++++++++++%7C+v14.17.3+++++++++++%7C+%0A%7C+OS++++++++++++++%7C+windows++++++++++++%7C%0A%7C+Prisma+Client+++%7C+2.30.3+++++++++++++%7C%0A%7C+Query+Engine++++%7C+undefined%7C%0A%7C+Database++++++++%7C+undefined%7C%0A%0A%0A%0A%23%23+Logs%0A%60%60%60%0Aprisma%3Aclient+clientVersion%3A+2.30.3%0Aprisma%3Aengine+Search+for+Query+Engine+in+C%3A%5CUsers%5CDocuments%5Cnode_modules%5C.prisma%5Cclient%0Aprisma%3Aclient+clientVersion%3A+2.30.3%0Aprisma%3Aengine+Search+for+Query+Engine+in+C%3A%5CUsers%5CDocuments%5Cnode_modules%5C.prisma%5Cclient%0Aprisma%3Aclient+clientVersion%3A+2.30.3%0Aprisma%3Aengine+Search+for+Query+Engine+in+C%3A%5CUsers%5CDocuments%5Cnode_modules%5C.prisma%5Cclient%0Aprisma%3Aclient+clientVersion%3A+2.30.3%0Aprisma%3Aengine+Search+for+Query+Engine+in+C%3A%5CUsers%5CDocuments%5Cnode_modules%5C.prisma%5Cclient%0Aprisma%3Aclient+clientVersion%3A+2.30.3%0Aprisma%3Aclient+clientVersion%3A+2.30.3%0Aprisma%3Aengine+Search+for+Query+Engine+in+C%3A%5CUsers%5C%5CDocuments%5C%5Cnode_modules%5C.prisma%5Cclient%0Aprisma%3Aengine+Search+for+Query+Engine+in+C%3A%5CUsers%5C%5Cnode_modules%5C.prisma%5Cclient%0Aprisma%3Aengine+%7B+cwd%3A+%27C%3A%5C%5CUsers%5C%8%5C%5CDocuments%5C%5C%5Cprisma%27+%7D%0Aprisma%3Aengine+Search+for+Query+Engine+in+C%3A%5CUsers%5CDocuments%5Cnode_modules%5C.prisma%5Cclient%0Aprisma%3Aengine+%7B+flags%3A+%5B+%27--enable-raw-queries%27%2C+%27--port%27%2C+%2752597%27+%5D+%7D%0Aprisma%3Aengine+stdout++Starting+a+postgresql+pool+with+9+connections.%0Aprisma%3Aengine+stdout++Started+http+server+on+http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A52597%0Aprisma%3Aengine+Search+for+Query+Engine+in+C%3A%5CUsers%5CDocuments%5Cnode_modules%5C.prisma%5Cclient%0Aprisma%3Aengine+stdout++PANIC+in+libs%5Cprisma-models%5Csrc%5Crecord.rs%3A161%3A30%0AInvalid+coercion+encountered%3A+ConversionFailure%28%22Uuid%2840ca7fbd-7a7e-4e34-9aa8-89a7f6048a6b%29%22%2C+%22Int%22%29%0Aprisma%3Aengine+%7B%0A++error%3A+Error%3A+read+ECONNRESET%0A++++++at+TCP.onStreamRead+%28internal%2Fstream_base_commons.js%3A209%3A20%29+%7B%0A++++errno%3A+-4077%2C%0A++++code%3A+%27ECONNRESET%27%2C%0A++++syscall%3A+%27read%27%0A++%7D%0A%7D%0Aprisma%3Aengine+%7B%0A++error%3A+Error%3A+connect+ECONNREFUSED+127.0.0.1%3A52597%0A++++++at+TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect+%5Bas+oncomplete%5D+%28net.js%3A1148%3A16%29+%7B%0A++++errno%3A+-4078%2C%0A++++code%3A+%27ECONNREFUSED%27%2C%0A++++syscall%3A+%27connect%27%2C%0A++++address%3A+%27127.0.0.1%27%2C%0A++++port%3A+52597%0A++%7D%0A%7D%0Aprisma%3Aengine+%7B%0A++error%3A+Error%3A+connect+ECONNREFUSED+127.0.0.1%3A52597%0A++++++at+TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect+%5Bas+oncomplete%5D+%28net.js%3A1148%3A16%29+%7B%0A++++errno%3A+-4078%2C%0A++++code%3A+%27ECONNREFUSED%27%2C%0A++++syscall%3A+%27connect%27%2C%0A++++address%3A+%27127.0.0.1%27%2C%0A++++port%3A+52597%0A++%7D%0A%7D%0A%60%60%60%0A%0A%23%23+Client+Snippet%0A%60%60%60ts%0A%2F%2F+PLEASE+FILL+YOUR+CODE+SNIPPET+HERE%0A%60%60%60%0A%0A%23%23+Schema%0A%60%60%60prisma%0A%2F%2F+PLEASE+ADD+YOUR+SCHEMA+HERE+IF+POSSIBLE%0A%60%60%60%0A%0A%23%23+Prisma+Engine+Query%0A%60%60%60%0Aquery+%7B%0A++findManyusers+%7B%0A++++id%0A++++email%0A++++firstName%0A++++lastName%0A++++models%5Csrc%5Crecord.rs%3A161%3A30%0AInvalid+coercion+encountered%3A+ConversionFailure%28%22Uuid%2840ca7fbd-7a7e-4e34-9aa8-89a7f6048a6b%29%22%2C+%22Int%22%29&template=bug_report.md
[2022-06-15T08:29:10.871Z] If you want the Prisma team to look into it, please open the link above ≡ƒÖÅ
[2022-06-15T08:29:10.875Z] To increase the chance of success, please post your schema and a snippet of
[2022-06-15T08:29:10.879Z] how you used Prisma Client in the issue.

[2022-06-15T08:29:10.885Z]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
[2022-06-15T08:29:10.888Z]     at async Object.module.exports.getUsers (C:\Users\Documents\folder\src\api\v1\prisma\routs\user.js:15:26) {
[2022-06-15T08:29:10.889Z]   clientVersion: '2.30.3'
[2022-06-15T08:29:10.890Z] }